# Почему цикл начинается с 1?

Tags: javascript, циклы

Почему проход второго цикла начинается с 1, а не с 0?

Сделайте функцию uniq, которая будет оставлять в массиве только уникальные элементы (то есть будет удалять дубли).

```js
function uniq(arr){
        for(var i = 0; i <arr.length; i++){
            for(var j = 1; j < arr.length; j++){
                if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
                    arr = delElem(arr,arr[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
    console.log(uniq([1,8,5,8,12,13,12]));
    
    function delElem(arr, num){
        var newarr =[];
        for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i] != num){
                newarr.push(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        return newarr;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы не сравнивать нулевой элемент с самим же собой

Answer (score 0):

```js
function uniq(arr){
        for(var i = 0; i <arr.length; i++){
            for(var j = 1; j < arr.length; j++){
                if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
                    arr = delElem(arr,arr[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
    console.log(uniq([1,2,3,2,1]));
    console.log(uniq([0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4]));
    
    function delElem(arr, num){
        var newarr =[];
        for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i] != num){
                newarr.push(arr[i]);
            }
        }
        return newarr;
    }
```

Собственно этих 2 примеров достаточно чтобы понять что код ни работает ну никак просто.

Основная ошибка - в обычном цикле по массиву удалять элементы. Ну и дополнительно лишние циклы. Пример (я не JS поэтому код чуть некрасивый как это хотя бы будет работать).

```js
function uniq(arr) {
  var p = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var u = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < p; j++) {
      if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
        u = false;
        break; //!!!!
      }
    }
    if (u)
      arr[p++] = arr[i];
  }
  return arr.splice(0, p);
}
console.log(uniq([1, 2, 3, 2, 1]));
console.log(uniq([0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4]));
```

Comment: Это медленное решение.

Comment: @And я знаю что можно использовать ассоциативный массив. Но в вопросе были циклы, я понял что человек хочет разобраться как оно работает.

Comment: Причем тут ассоциативный массив, смотрите мой пример. за что тут вам + дали, не понятно вообще.

Comment: @And переменная obj из вашего ответа - это и есть ассоциативный массив

Comment: @PavelMayorov - это объект, а не массив.

Comment: @And ассоциативный массив - это общее надъязыковое понятие. В языке js в роли ассоциативного массива может использоваться объект.

Comment: @And так оно и отличается. Словом "ассоциативный". Это не религия, а устоявшийся термин.

Answer (score -4):

```
function unique(arr) {
    if (!arr.length) {
        return[];
    }
    for (var i = 0, obj = {}; i < arr.length; i++) {
        obj[arr[i]] = true;
    }
    return Object.keys(obj);
}
console.log(unique([1, 8, 5, 8, 12, 13, 12])); // ["1", "5", "8", "12", "13"]
```

Comment: @АнастасияКотова вы не тому цитату отправили =), выберите в качестве решения, нажав галочку слева.

Comment: В условии нигде не сказано, что элементами массива могут быть только числа. Соответственно, `unique([1, '1', null, 'null'])` тут отработает неверно. И еще, судя по коду автора, требуется оставить только те элементы, которые встречаются ровно один раз, то есть, от `[1, 1, 2]` должно остаться только `[2]`

Comment: Иными словами, вместо объекта нужно использовать Set...

Comment: @Yaant, вы читать умеете: `которая будет оставлять в массиве только уникальные элементы (то есть будет удалять дубли)`, во вторых, все там верно отработает и из вашего примера останется: `["1", "null"]` - то есть уникальные. И это работает не только на числах но и на строках и других типах, к примеру `[1, '1', null, 'null','стр','стр']` - вернет в итоге: `["1", "null", "стр"]`, все верно. И за что минус то в итоге? Потому, что вы читать не умеете?

Comment: @And Вы серьезно хотите сказать, что `null` и `"null"` - это одно и то же? Во-вторых, тот же вопрос и Вам, умеете ли читать Вы? :) Сказано "оставлять в массиве только уникальные". В массиве `[1, 1, 2]` уникальное значение ровно одно — `2`. Значит, только его и надо оставить.

Comment: И кстати говоря, минус не мой. :)

Comment: @Yaant, да кто вам сказал, что там уникально должно остаться только 2-ка? Вы что там сам себе на уме, придумали, что тс якобы хочет 2-ку, и твердите, хотя на самом деле, тс меня поблагодарил. Все верно я сделал. И этот вариант быстрее предыдущего. А с вами сударь, все ясно, читать научитесь, а придумывать себе не нужно.

Comment: Ладно, спорить бессмысленно, Вы все равно игнорируете аргументы. :) Но всё-таки, что насчёт равенства `null` и `'null'`?

Comment: @Yaant, прочитайте про `Object.keys` и все поймете.